# How to integrate angular2-materialize in a project created with angular cli

Tags: angularjs, angular, materialize

I want to use the `Materialize CSS` Framework in my project.
I set up a project the `Angular CLI` using `ng new BLABLA`

After that I've followed the steps in [this](https://github.com/InfomediaLtd/angular2-materialize#installing--configuring-angular2-materialize-in-projects-created-with-angular-cliwebpack-100-beta11-webpack8) guide.

However, if I use `ng serve` to start the project, I get this error in the browser:

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'jQuery.easing.swing')
```

my angular-cli.json

```
{
  "project": {
    "version": "1.0.0-beta.15",
    "name": "blabla"
  },
  "apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": "assets",
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.json",
      "prefix": "app",
      "mobile": false,
      "styles": [
        "styles.css"
      ],
      "scripts": [
        "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
        "../node_modules/materialize-css/dist/js/materialize.js"
      ],
      "environments": {
        "source": "environments/environment.ts",
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    }
  ],
  "addons": [],
  "packages": [],
  "e2e": {
    "protractor": {
      "config": "./protractor.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "test": {
    "karma": {
      "config": "./karma.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "defaults": {
    "styleExt": "css",
    "prefixInterfaces": false
  }
}
```

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

import { MaterializeModule } from 'angular2-materialize';
import "materialize-css";
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    MaterializeModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

what you need to do is as follow:

add to your global css file this line:
**@import "../node_modules/materialize-css/dist/css/materialize.css";**

and remove this line
**import "materialize-css";**
from app.module.ts

also make sure you installed the correct jquery version better if you run this in any case:
npm install jquery@^2.2.4 --save

doing it worked for me. [good luck]

Answer (score 0):

I also found that if you run npm rebuild after making the entries in the apps[0].scripts and apps[0].styles properties of angular-cli.json everthing works, and you don't have to add the @import to the styles.css.

I found this information on Mike Lynch's site http://mikelynchgames.com/software-development/setting-up-and-using-angular-2-cli/

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively if you want to use original `sass` and  not the `DIST` version of materialzie css because you might want override colors and other variables you can use this...

Import materialize css in your main styles.sass file like this.

```
// override fonts path to prevent build errors (or use resolve-url loader)
$roboto-font-path: "../node_modules/materialize-css/fonts/roboto/"

// optionally override color variables eg: ...
$primary-color: color("materialize-purple");

@import "~materialize-css/sass/materialize"
```

Comment: Sass version of materialize is really confusing on how to install it in a clean way